# How to setup a networked Brother printer (Brother_DCP_L2520DW_series) on Raspberry Pi with Raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, cups, network-printers, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to use a networked Brother printer with my RPI3 (Raspbian Stretch).

I tried several tutorials :

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194147

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40722/how-to-install-cups-driver-gutenprint

https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp1512_us_eu&faqid=faq00000366_031

None of these solutions work.

I adde the printer inside CUPS browser utility (http://localhost:631). I can print a Test PAge from here.

But when i want to use Command Line, the printer isn't recognized.

When i use `lpstat -p`for listing alvailable printers, i got this log in Command Line Terminal :

```
lpstat: server-error-operation-not-supported
```

When i'm trying to use command like `lp` I get this error line :

```
lp: Error - scheduler not responding.
```

I'm totally stucked. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Remove all CUPS installation

```
sudo apt-get sudo /etc/init.d/cups stop
sudo apt-get purge cups
sudo rm -rf /etc/cups
```

And reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

For convenience, you can add Printer SEttings in Raspbian Menu

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-printer
```

For enabling Recto Verso Printing, install

```
sudo apt-get install gtklp
```